# Python: Adding Copies of a Character in a String

Tags: python, string, character

I'm trying to figure out how to add copies of a character in a string, as long as the character is a vowel. 
For example, if I input the word copy('app'), it would ideally return 'aaaapp!'. I know that strings are immutable, but there has to be a way! I've been staring at this for hours.

Note: I don't want a solution to my code, preferably just a hint to get me in the right direction. 
Edit: Thanks for all the help!

One of my ideas was: word += word + i*4 but that returns something like 'appaaaa!'

```
def copy(word):
     "('string') ==> ('string') Adds four copies of vowel and an '!' to the string"
     vowel = 'aeiouAEIOU'
     for i in word:
          if i in vowel:
                #Missing code Here
     return word + '!'
```

Comment: Don't worry so much about strings being immutable. Just make a new string. You only need to worry about it if they are bigger strings (like kilo bytes or mega bytes) The 'cost' of making a new string is usually cheaper in computer terms than manipulating an existing string in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compose a separate string while you scan your input:

```
s = ''
for i in word:
  if i in vowel:
     s += i*4
  else:
     s += i
s += '!'
```

Comment: Here, it might be more efficient to build a list.  `lst.append(i)` or `lst.extend(i*4)` rather than `s += i` or `s += i*4`.  Then at the end, you `''.join(lst)`.

Comment: I have followed the OP idea... I think he wants to understand how his idea can be completed to a working code. Don't think he is interested in efficiency.

Comment: I actually used this! At first, it wasn't returning any consonants, and then I fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `re.sub` pretty easily:

```
>>> re.sub('([aeiouAEIOU])',r'\1\1\1\1','string')
'striiiing'
```

Or, if you want the number of substitutions to be variable:

```
>>> N=4
>>> re.sub('([aeiouAEIOU])',r'\1'*N,'string')
'striiiing'
```

Answer (score 3):

The key is to make a new string.  If the character is not a vowel, you just copy it to the new string.  If it's a vowel, you copy *four* copies of it to the new string.  Then you return the new string.  Here's one way to do it:

```
def copy(word):
    vowels = set ("AEIOUaeiou")
    return "".join(char * 4 if char in vowels else char for char in word) + "!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy each character of the string to a list, insert vowels at your leisure and then join the list back to a string: ''.join(mylist))